# Como leer campo por campo de un archivo XML?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

estoy importando un archivo XML desde ASP.NET MVC, con EF Core, ya leo el archivo, pero no logro traerme cada campo de este, si no se viene por nodo o en grupo y este debo guardarlo en una tabla por cada campo que traiga: Este es un registro del archivo XML

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Nominas>
<NominaIndividual>
<Periodo FechaIngreso ="2000-06-21" FechaRetiro ="" FechaLiquidacionInicio ="2021-08-01" FechaLiquidacionFin ="2021-08-31" TiempoLaborado ="7630" FechaGen ="2021-09-14" />
<FechasPagos>
<FechaPago>2021-08-31</FechaPago>
</FechasPagos>
<Devengados>
<Basico DiasTrabajados ="0" SueldoTrabajado ="0" />
<Transporte AuxilioTransporte ="" ViaticoManuAlojS ="" ViaticoManuAlojNS ="" />
</NominaIndividual>
</Nominas>
```

Con este codigo leo el archivo pero no puedo leer cada campo de este:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   List<Studentdetail> students = new List<Studentdetail>();
   
   try
   {
      doc.Load("E:\\ExampleXML\\MelecNomina.xml");

      foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/Nominas/NominaIndividual"))
      {
         students.Add(new Studentdetail
         {
            name = node["FechasPagos"].InnerText,
            class_Section = node["Devengados"].InnerText,
            roll_no = node["Deducciones"].InnerText
         });
      }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }

    return view(students);
}
```

Espero sus comentarios, saludos

Comment: Pon la estructura de tu XML, muestra un ejemplo con el contenido de tu xml

Comment: Este es parte del codigo:
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Nominas>
<NominaIndividual>
<Periodo FechaIngreso ="2000-06-21" FechaRetiro ="" FechaLiquidacionInicio ="2021-08-01" FechaLiquidacionFin ="2021-08-31" TiempoLaborado ="7630" FechaGen ="2021-09-14" />
<FechasPagos>
            <FechaPago>2021-08-31</FechaPago>
        </FechasPagos>
<Devengados>
            <Basico DiasTrabajados ="0" SueldoTrabajado ="0" />
            <Transporte AuxilioTransporte ="" ViaticoManuAlojS ="" ViaticoManuAlojNS ="" />
</NominaIndividual>
</Nominas>
Este es parte del codigo, gracias

Comment: edita tu pregunta y pon ahi el XML

Comment: Japv, agregue o logre agregar el codigo en la pregunta se ve mas entendible, espero sus comentarios